# Call Specific function within PHP with Parameters

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm new to php/javascript and I'm trying to call a specific function within php file from javascript. 
My code is as follows:

```
<script>
        function load($dID) {

          $.ajax({
                    url: "myPHP.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {ID: $dID, method: "myFunc"},
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        // handle output here
                    }
                }); // Ajax Call
    }
</script>
```

Within php I'm looking to call function myFunc and within it I'm looking to use ID parameter:

```
<?php

function myFunc {

  $res = $ID; // return value will be processed based on $ID value

  return $res;
}
?>
```

I can't seem to find the right way to set up php in order to call the right function or access ID parameter. I tried:

```
   if(isset($_POST['method'])) {

   }
```

But I'm getting errors.

Can you please help? What would be right way to call the right function and access the parameters within it.

Answer (score 0):

First the function syntax is wrong. it must have scobes.

```
<?php

$method  = isset($_POST['method']) ? $_POST['method'] : null;
$id= isset($_POST['ID']) ? $_POST['ID'] : null;


if(!function_exists($method)){    
  die(json_encode(['response' => 'Method not exists']));
} 

echo json_encode(['result' => $method($id)]); // you might want to send json response


function myFunc($ID) {

  $res = $ID; // return value will be processed based on $ID value

  return $res;
}
?>
```

Would also remove the `?>` at the end of the file because it can output new lines which are might be added after it.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but if(!function_exists($method)) returns true (and dies). If I use an explicit call to check for the function - if(!function_exists('myFunc')) - it works. So for some reason data is not being passed to php. Any ideas what I could look at? Thank you!

Comment: `if(!function_exists($method))`  checks if the function is defined. To check if everything is ok with the ajax request open Develpoer Tools -> Newtwork -> XHR in the browser and try to execute dhe ajax call. There you will find what is being posted and also the respone.